# make framer motion fade in & out based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

im just trying to get some text to fade in and out based on the scroll position

i am using framer motion

here is my code:

```js
    const ref = useRef(null)
    const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
        target: ref,
        offset: ["start end", "end end"],
    })
    const opacity = useTransform(
        scrollYProgress,
        [0, 0.5, 1],
        [0, 1, 0],
    )

// ...

        <div ref={ref} className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center border border-blue-600 text-7xl h-screen">
            <motion.div
                style={{
                    opacity: opacity,
                }}
            >
                hello
            </motion.div>
        </div>
```

i want it so when the scroll position is centered on the div (scrollYProgress == 0.5) then the opacity is 100%, and scrolling up or down from that point fades it out progressively based on scrollYProgress

the text is only fading out when scrolling top to bottom, not fading in & out as desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your offset to `["start center", "end center"]`.

From [Framer Motion's docs](https://www.framer.com/motion/use-scroll/##scroll-offsets):

> `offset` is an array of at least two intersections. An intersection describes a point when the `target` and `container` meet. So for example, `"start end"` means when the **start of the target** meets the **end of the container**.

In your case, the `target` is the div you gave the ref to. The `container` is the viewport. By setting your offset to `["start end", "end end"]`, you are telling Framer Motion that the scrollYProgress should be 0 when the **start** of the div is at the **end** of the viewport and 1 when the **end** of the div is at the **end** of the viewport. This can be a bit tricky to work out without a visualization. I made [this example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/usescroll-offset-visualization-gmhwl3?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A20%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clptzx9xu0007356hddrt7c57%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clptzx9xt0002356hj9viewnp%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clptzx9xt0004356hrynrxeaa%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clptzx9xt0006356hfihsoter%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clptzx9xt0002356hj9viewnp%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clptzx9xt0002356hj9viewnp%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpu1s4yk0002356h3utwwad2%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A20%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A1%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A20%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A1%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpu1s4yk0002356h3utwwad2%2522%257D%252C%2522clptzx9xt0006356hfihsoter%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clptzx9xt0006356hfihsoter%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clptzx9xt0005356hfx9tx5x7%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clptzx9xt0005356hfx9tx5x7%2522%257D%252C%2522clptzx9xt0004356hrynrxeaa%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clptzx9xt0003356h6byc9g3d%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clptzx9xt0004356hrynrxeaa%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clptzx9xt0003356h6byc9g3d%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) to help see what "start", "center", and "end" mean when it comes to the offsets.

Setting your offset to `["start center", "end start"]` may also be a result you are looking for. The beauty of Framer Motion is that you can play around and accomplish these fine tuned animations.